# cordova-tools Error processing "launch": Unable to find webview | Ionic 4 - Angular 7 on VS code

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ios-webkit-debug-proxy

i need an help...So my target is debug my ionic apps with visual studio code and breakpoint inside.
So my configuration is:

- Mac OS Mojave
- iOS 12.3.1
- Visual Studio (last update may 2019)
- Xcode 10.2.1 installed
- Cordova Tools on Visual Studio Code installed (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.cordova-tools)
- On safari on iPhone i set Safari -> advanced -> Inspector web on true
- ios-webkit-debug-proxy installed and intercpetor connected (as you can see)

[image]

So, my configuration (launch.json) is:

```
   {
        "name": "Attach to iOS on device",
        "type": "cordova",
        "request": "attach",
        "platform": "ios",
        "target": "mytarget device",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "port": 9222,
        "attachDelay": 5000
    },
    {
        "name": "Run iOS on device",
        "type": "cordova",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios",
        "target": "my target device",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        // "ionicLiveReload": true,
        "devServerTimeout" : 420000,
        "port": 9222,
        "attachDelay": 5000
    }
```

In order to run, i've `Run iOS on device` and after app starts on the device i've run `Attach to iOS on device`. So when i think everything works: visual studio return me this error:

```
Attaching to ios
Configuring debugging proxy
Unable to find webview <- this is my error.
```

I can't to resolve this error, how can i do to works and find the webview?
I've try to set this:

```
"attachDelay": 5000
```

but without success.
Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem! In the past this worked.

Comment: anyone solve this problem?

Comment: facing the same issue... Did anyone solve it? any help on this is very much appreciated...

Comment: @DurgaVundavalli my solution is create another project ionic and replace the app folder with the old project folder.

Comment: Thankyou for your instant reponse... I tried it on a new application but the same issue..   [cordova-tools] Error processing "launch": An error occurred while handling message: GET_RUN_ARGUMENTSError: connect ENOENT /tmp/vscodecordova-c2f4ec370dd85c5e45a0f940797f93c9.sock